How can I fixing Rstudio UTF-8 And Matrix Error
I'm getting a UTF-8 error every time I press a key, and it's causing issues when loading Matrix.
I'm experiencing a recurring problem where every character I type in RStudio triggers an error message. This is compounded by the fact that many packages are loading with errors, preventing me from working effectively. I've been unable to pinpoint the specific cause of these issues.
As a troubleshooting step, I began by updating the R version to the latest release. Following this, I reinstalled RStudio and the Matrix package. Unfortunately, these actions did not rectify the persistent problem.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
